# How do I change the display icon of my Chrome Extension to a bigger size?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I don't want to use the small icon. I want to have a bigger one instead (just like the ones in the image below). I searched and investigated in the dashboard but found nowhere to upload that sized image.

Thanks for any kind of help!

[image: I don't want to use the small icon. I want to have a bigger one instead (just like the ones in the image below)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of elements in Chrome Web Store (CWS): [apps](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1050586) and [extensions](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=154007).

If element in CWS is an extension it is indicated by displaying it's logo inside the picture of a gray puzzle. For apps puzzle is not displayed making more space for a logo (and that's why the bigger one is used).

Therefore, if you have a chrome extension it's logo will always be displayed small and inside a puzzle in CWS. You can't change that.